# Des expressions pour choisir un objet sans préférence

Tags: vocabulaire, mathématiques

En lisant, j’ai vu plusieurs manières de dire qu’on choisit un objet parmi plusieurs objets, de façon qu’aucune chose n’ait plus de chance d’être prise que l’autre. Ceci est une tentative de trier ces manières. J’ai besoin de vos renseignements pour améliorer cet aperçu.

**Tirer à coup perdu**, ça vient d’un jeu de cartes ? Selon le Wiktionnaire, cela veut dire « tirer au hasard » ou empêcher quelqu’un de s’emparer de quelque chose. Si je lis qu’on tire au coup perdu, je me représente dans l’esprit qu’un joueur tient des cartes en éventail et un autre joueur qui ne peut voir que leur dos en prend une. Je dirais qu’on peut aussi dire qu’on tire une balle à coup perdu d’une boite. S’il ne s’agit pas d’un jeu, mais d’un vecteur aléatoire, cette manière de dire ne convient pas, surtout si l’espace probabilisé n’est pas dénombrable.

Contrairement à ce qui précède, **choisir aléatoirement** a l’air d’une bonne tournure pour dire qu’une variable aléatoire prend une valeur. Selon le Wiktionnaire, aléatoire ne veut pas seulement dire « au hasard », mais aussi « osé ». J’ai donc un peu peur que cette tournure laisse entendre que quelqu’un fait un choix malavisé.

Je crains pareillement que la combinaison **choisir par hasard** ait pour effet des contresens, car elle ressemble à *trouver par hasard*, c’est-à-dire qu’elle souligne un truc issu du choix tandis que je cherche à décrire comment le fait de choisir se déroule. Je ne veux pas que la façon de parler ait à voir avec ce qui sort du processus. C’est pour cela que je pense qu’on se méprend facilement quand on entend ou lit une telle tournure.

**Tirer au sort** me semble plus solennel que les autres, car le mot « sort » paraît solennel. J’ai aussi lu qu’on dit que les conscrits *tirent au sort* si on élit des hommes parmi eux pour les envoyer à la bataille.

Que pensez de mes idées ? Quelles tournures peuvent encore être ajoutées ?

Comment: Jamais entendu la variante *tirer à coup perdu* dans le contexte mathématique. Est-ce que ça ne pourrait pas venir d'une volonté de désigner le cas du tirage aléatoire et successif de plusieurs éléments dans un ensemble, en précisant que les éléments déjà sélectionnés ne font plus partie de l'ensemble pour les tirages suivants ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dans un contexte mathématique, les expressions les plus couramment utilisées sont «choisir aléatoirement», «tirer aléatoirement». «Au hasard» est également possible, et un chouilla moins formel. «Aléatoire» peut signifier «risqué» dans la vie courante, mais ce sous-entendu péjoratif ne s'applique pas dans un cadre mathématique.

Pour insister sur le fait que la loi de probabilité est uniforme, on pourra préciser «tirer au hasard uniformément» ou «aléatoirement de manière uniforme».

«Par hasard» ne convient pas; l'expression est plutôt utilisé pour un évènement («J'ai rencontré un ami par hasard»). «Tirer une carte par hasard» semble vouloir dire que la personne a tiré une carte sans le vouloir.

«Tirer au sort» convient pour une loterie ou la désignation d'un volontaire, mais je l'ai rarement entendu utilisé dans un cadre mathématique (sauf pour raconter une histoire autour d'un exercice).

Je ne connaissais pas l'expression «Tirer à coup perdu». Il semble qu'elle concerne le fait de tirer avec une arme à feu. Cela me semble obscur et peu adapté.

Comment: En effet, "tirer à coup perdu" est une expression peut utilisée synonyme de "tirer à balles perdues" (plus commune à mon avis) à savoir soit tirer dans le vide à but d'intimidation soit tirer sans viser au hasard (dans une foule ou autour d'une cible par exemple).

Answer (score 4):

Il y a plusieurs expressions qui peuvent être utilisées pour choisir un objet parmi d'autre sans qu'aucun n'ait plus de chance d'être choisi:

- **Choisir au hasard**: et non pas **choisir par hasard**. On peut se rencontrer dans la rue par hasard, mais l'on choisit au hasard. C'est sans doute l'expression la plus courante pour la vie de tous les jours.

  > Quel pull vas-tu mettre aujourd'hui?
  >
  > Je ne sais pas, je vais choisir au hasard en mettant la main dans le tiroir.
- **Choisir aléatoirement**: possède exactement la même signification que choisir au hasard mais c'est une expression plus employée dans le domaine scientifique. En informatique, on parle par exemple de générateur de nombres aléatoires, et donc de tirer un nombre aléatoirement.

  > Je suis en train de faire un programme pour jouer au poker, et j'ai besoin de choisir aléatoirement les cartes des joueurs.
- **Tirer au sort**: exprime aussi le fait de faire un choix au hasard. C'est une expression plutôt employée dans le domaine sportif, par exemple tirer au sort l'équipe qui débutera le match. On trouve évidemment cette tournure dans les jeux de hasard (tirage au sort dans une loterie par exemple).

  > Est-ce que tu penses que l'on va gagner la coupe du monde de football?
  >
  > Je ne sais pas, cela dépend un peu du tirage au sort.
- Choisir **au petit bonheur la chance**: C'est une expression moins courante, mais qui je trouve a son charme. L'expression vient du mot **heur** qui signifiait **hasard**. Au petit bonheur veut donc dire vraiment au hasard. En y ajoutant **chance**, on accentue le fait que c'est vraiment au hasard.

  > Où vas-tu aller pour les vacances?
  >
  > Je ne sais pas, je vais prendre la voiture et aller vers le sud au petit bonheur la chance.
  >
  > J'ai choisi mon ticket de loterie au petit bonheur la chance.

Answer (score 1):

Au quotidien, j’emploierais tout simplement « choisir *au hasard* ». Dans le Trésor de la langue française, [voir les acceptions 3 et 4 c)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hasard).